# How to delete whole previous word instead of just 1 character?

Tags: linux, keyboard

There are some similar questions about bash or vim, but I am asking about the whole system in general.

Is there a way to make <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete the whole previous word?

For example. when I'm typing in browser, it should work there as well. Is there anything I can do to achieve it?

I'm on Linux, if it's important.

Comment: For such automation you should search for "Autohotkey alternative for Linux" (I'm on Windows only so can't help any further). If you find a tool with same functionality it would be possible to emulate various command combos e.g. "select one word and delete it" or whatever shortcuts the app in focus supports by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "whole system in general", unfortunately. Some graphical programs are written in the GTK toolkit and use text-fields (and keyboard shortcuts) that are provided by GTK; others are written in Qt and use text input from Qt; browsers usually do their own custom thing (though they at least try to mimic GTK or Qt shortcuts); and terminal-based programs such as Bash live in a completely different world from everything else.

- In most graphical programs, use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←Backspace</kbd>** to delete the last word up to a punctuation character. This is a common standard that works in GTK, Qt, Chrome, Firefox, and *most* other toolkits.
- In web browsers, the above shortcuts should work... but beware that often websites have fancy text input fields which implement *their own* shortcuts overriding what the browser does. For example, right here on SuperUser, the "write an answer" box makes Ctrl+Z (Undo) work completely differently than the browser normally would.
- In Bash (and other programs using Readline), use either **<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←Backspace</kbd>** to delete up to the last punctuation character – yes, **Alt**, not Ctrl – or **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>** to delete up to the last *space*. (For example, when typing a path, one deletes the whole path as a single "word" while the other deletes just the last component.)
- In various full-screen terminal programs such as Vim, Emacs, Nano, etc. there are no common shortcuts – literally every single program does things differently. (Sometimes even different areas *within* the same app work differently.) Sometimes the same "Emacs-style" Alt+Backspace and Ctrl+W will work, sometimes not.
- In terminal programs using raw line-based tty input, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>. (This and Ctrl+U are the only shortcuts that the tty itself provides.)

Comment: ok i thought maybe there are some system-wide programs that count the number of characters in a word and stop counting when a space or punctuation is found. Then by pressing some combination put n Backspaces instead of 1

Comment: Would be difficult to make such a program work reliably, as it wouldn't cope with moving the cursor by mouse, or text added through auto-completion (e.g. Tab in shells), or even with backspacing immediately after Ctrl+V paste.